# Folium colormap legend equal bin width

Tags: python, plot, colormap, folium

I am plotting a map with folium where each color of a region depends on the amount of incidents.
So i need a legend, but the problem is that I have a few very high outliners which leads to following legend.

```
from branca.colormap import linear

colormap = linear.YlGn_09.to_step(
    index=[1,50, 100, 1000, 1000000]
)
```

[image]

Is it possible to make the width of all bins equal, so that it is possible to also see the small bins in the legend?

Comment: Try using a logarithmic (`log(x)`) transformation on your data before plotting.  This will linearize the data, rather then mapping your linear colormap onto an exponential scale.